# Generate the nth permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

I'm just trying to write a little algorithm. I've got nine objects, so there's 9! permutations. My question is, is there a way of turning a number from 1 to 9! into a permutation?

for example, f(1)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], f(2)=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,8] or something similar.

Each number should have a unique ordering, and vice versa.

I know it's possible with code, I was just wondering if there's a nicer way of doing with just maths.

Comment: This is a classic question in programming. It is better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Look up “ranking and unranking permutations”.

Comment: @AndrejBauer  - A question becomes a "question in programming" when its mathematical aspects have already been clarified, which is hardly the case here.